# Parsing AWS Lambda Response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Experts,

I have the below as a response of a lambda invocation from within another lambda function

Now when I try to parse this response in the invoking lambda I am just unable to get the attributes of the response

```
 let response = await checkStatus(userId); //this invokes a lambda function
 console.log("Status Response:", response);
 console.log("First Array Object:" , (response[0]))
```

Outputs

```
Status Response: [
{
    "id": 209,
    "userId": "AA001",
    "email": null,
    "password": "123456",
    "firstName": "Lalit",
    "lastName": "Devreddy  ",
    "agencyId": 3,
    "role": "CENTRAL_TEAM",
    "isActive": "Y",
    "isLocked": "N",
    "profilePicture": null,
    "createdBy": "A001",
    "updatedBy": "A001",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-19T14:38:28.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-19T14:38:28.000Z",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "active": "Y"
}
]
```

First Array Object:

```
[
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` is a JSON string, so `response[0]` is just the first character in the string. Use JSON.parse to get the data

```
 let response = await checkStatus(userId); 
 let data = JSON.parse(response);
 console.log("First Array Object:" , data[0]);
```